# SendGrid Content Templating with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ecmascript-6, sendgrid

## How do I template SendGrid's content with Nodejs?

I am trying to send emails from contact form in an application using SendGrid. I have a Google Cloud Function that I am calling via an HTTP post. I am able to pass in the form data as a JSON object to my Google Cloud Function, and display a raw JSON object in my email content, but when I try to template my SendGrid content, the JSON object's properties keep coming back as undefined. How do I display my different `formData` properties within my SendGrid email content?

Here is the code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const sg = require('sendgrid')(
  process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY || '<my-api-key-placed-here>'
);

exports.contactMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  contactMail(req.body);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.send("Mail Successfully Sent!");
})


function contactMail(formData) {
  const mailRequest = sg.emptyRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/v3/mail/send',
    body: {
      personalizations: [{
        to: [{ email: 'my.email@gmail.com' }],
        subject: 'Contact Us Form Submitted'
      }],
      from: { email: 'noreply@email-app.firebaseapp.com' },
      content: [{
        type: 'text/plain',
        value: `
          You have received a contact us form submission. Here is the data:
          Name: ${formData.userFirstName} ${formData.userLastName}
          Email: ${formData.userEmail}
          Subject: ${formData.formSubject}
          Message: ${formData.formMessage}
        `
      }]
    }
  });

  sg.API(mailRequest, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Mail not sent; see error message below.');
    } else {
      console.log('Mail sent successfully!');
    }
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

This displays undefined for each template expression.

However if my content section is set to this:

```js
content: [{
  type: 'text/plain',
  value: formData
}]
```

Then the email content is displayed as a raw JSON object.

How do I clean up my SendGrid email content and display my JSON data in a formatted, cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my `req.body` was a text string, not a JSON object.

Using `const formData = JSON.parse(req.body);` and then passing this variable to `contactMail` will properly display the JSON object's properties in an ES6 template literal.